# ProgressBar JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Necesito inicar una progressBar cuando ejecute un metodo y que termine cuando el metodo termine de procesar, este es le metodo.

```
  @FXML
private void procesarImagen(ActionEvent event) {

    ArrayList<String> col = null;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
            int cont = 0;
            int acum = 0;
        procesamientoImagen pi = new procesamientoImagen();    




          Map<String, Integer> color = pi.procesmaientoImagen(a);

        TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(color);

           for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
 //     labelColor.setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+entry.getKey());


          acum = acum+entry.getValue();

           }
           System.out.println("Total Colores: "+acum);
           pb = new ProgressBar(0);
              int prog = 0;
           col = new ArrayList<>();
         ci =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
          for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
 //     labelColor.setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+entry.getKey());
      //   System.out.println("Color: "+entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue());
         String colorsImg = entry.getKey();
         float total = (float) (entry.getValue()*100)/acum ;     
         col.add(entry.getKey());
         ci.add(new colorInf("0",df.format(total),colorsImg)); 
         pb.setProgress(prog++);
    //          System.out.println("% "+df.format(total)); 

           }

               TblColor.setItems(ci); 


  // PLANTAS SANAS
   rangosPlagas r = new rangosPlagas();
    ArrayList<String> rango =null;

    procesamientoImagen pi2 = new procesamientoImagen();
    Map<String, Integer> color2 = pi2.procesmaientoImagen(r.plantaSana());
    rango = new  ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap2 = new TreeMap<>(color2);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap2.entrySet()) {
      //  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        rango.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    int resultado = 0;
    for (String co : col) {
     for (String ra : rango) {      

        if(ra.equals(co) ){
   //         System.out.println(ra+"Esta en el rango");
            resultado = 1;
        }
    }                
        if (resultado == 1) {
            tx.setText("Plantas Sanas");
            colorR.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2a2475");
        }

    }



    // PLANTAS SANAS

    ArrayList<String> rangoTrips =null;

    procesamientoImagen pi3 = new procesamientoImagen();
    Map<String, Integer> color3 = pi3.procesmaientoImagen(r.trips());
    rangoTrips = new  ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap3 = new TreeMap<>(color3);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap3.entrySet()) {
      //  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        rangoTrips.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    int resultado2 = 0;
    for (String co : col) {
     for (String ra : rangoTrips) {      

        if(ra.equals(co) ){
     //       System.out.println(ra+"Esta en el rango");
            resultado2 = 1;
        }
    }                



    }
      if (resultado2 == 1) {
            txTrips.setText("Posibles Incidencias de Trips en la planta");
            colorRT.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6b3d44");
        }





   // PLANTAS SANAS

    ArrayList<String> rangoMinador =null;

    procesamientoImagen pi4 = new procesamientoImagen();
    Map<String, Integer> color4 = pi4.procesmaientoImagen(r.minador());
    rangoMinador = new  ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap4 = new TreeMap<>(color4);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap4.entrySet()) {
      //  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        rangoMinador.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    int resultado3 = 0;
    for (String co : col) {
     for (String ra : rangoMinador ) {      

        if(ra.equals(co) ){
     //       System.out.println(ra+"Esta en el rango");
            resultado3 = 1;
        }
    }                



    }
      if (resultado3 == 1) {
            txMinador.setText("Posibles Incidencias de Minador en la planta");
            colorRM.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2f527c");
        }


      // PLANTAS SANAS

    ArrayList<String> rangoPasador =null;

    procesamientoImagen pi5 = new procesamientoImagen();
    Map<String, Integer> color5 = pi5.procesmaientoImagen(r.pasador());
    rangoPasador = new  ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap5 = new TreeMap<>(color5);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap5.entrySet()) {
      //  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        rangoPasador.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    int resultado4 = 0;
    for (String co : col) {
     for (String ra : rangoPasador ) {      

        if(ra.equals(co) ){
    //        System.out.println(ra+"Esta en el rango");
            resultado4 = 1;
        }
    }                



    }
      if (resultado4 == 1) {
            txPasador.setText("Posibles Incidencias de Pasador en la planta");
            colorRP.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #739bbf");
        }


      modificarCelda(colorFull);
             trips.setVisible(true);
            pasador.setVisible(true);
            minador.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo esta clase que diseñe cuando estaba aprendiendo pero que me fue de mucha utilidad, puedes instanciarlas todas las veces que quieras y correr procesos en paralelos sin ningún problema.

```
public class Barra_Progreso {
private double maximo, actual;
private String informacion, titulo;

private ProgressBar barra;
private Label etiqueta;

public Barra_Progreso(double maximo, double actual, String informacion, String titulo) {
    this.maximo = maximo;
    this.actual = actual;
    this.informacion = informacion;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    //this.segundo_plano();
}

public double getMaximo() {
    return maximo;
}

public void setMaximo(double maximo) {
    this.maximo = maximo;
}

public double getActual() {
    return actual;
}

public void setActual(double actual) {
    this.actual = actual;
}

public String getInformacion() {
    return informacion;
}

public void setInformacion(String informacion) {
    this.informacion = informacion;
}




public void interfaz_grafica(){

    final Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle(titulo);

    barra = new ProgressBar();
    barra.setLayoutX(14.0);barra.setLayoutY(26.0);
    barra.setPrefWidth(394.0);barra.setPrefHeight(40.0);
    barra.setProgress(actual);

    etiqueta = new Label(informacion);
    etiqueta.setLayoutX(14.0);etiqueta.setLayoutY(84.0);
    etiqueta.setPrefWidth(394.0);


    Pane panel = new Pane();        
    panel.setPrefWidth(422.0);panel.setPrefHeight(118.0);

    panel.getChildren().addAll(barra,etiqueta);

    Scene escena = new Scene(panel);
    escena.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                        @Override
                                     public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                                      stage.setX(event.getScreenX());
                                      stage.setY(event.getScreenY());
                                     }
                                    });
    stage.setScene(escena);
    stage.show();


}

public void segundo_plano(){        
            this.interfaz_grafica();

    Task tarea = new Task() {                        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
        //    System.out.println("CORRIENDO PROGRAMA: "+actual+" - "+maximo);

             while(true){

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {                 
          //                  System.out.println("calculo: "+(actual/maximo));
                            barra.setProgress((actual/maximo));
                            etiqueta.setText(informacion);                                
                        }
                    });

                 double valor = (actual/maximo);  
                 System.out.println("ACTUALIZANDO VALORES ->"+actual+" - "+maximo);
                 if(valor>=1.0) break;  
                try {
                    new Thread().sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Barra_Progreso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {             
            return null;
        }
    };

    new Thread(tarea).start();

}

}//fin de la clase
```

Comment: Cual metodo puedo incluir en mi funcion, porque creo una nueva instancia del progessBar y solo me sale la barra cuando mi funcion termina y quiero que salaga cuando inicie, y ademas solo me aparece la barra pero sin cargar.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo una implementacion completa

```
public class barra_progreso extends SwingWorker<Double, Integer>{



private registro_masivo rm;
    private final JLabel etiqueta;
    // Barra de progreso que vamos a ir incrementando.
    private final JProgressBar progreso;

/**
 * Le pasamos la etiqueta que tiene que poner "Hecho" cuando termine la
 * tarea y el barra de progreso que queremos que se vaya a actualizar.
 *
 * @param unaEtiqueta
 * @param unaBarraProgreso
 */
public barra_progreso(JLabel unaEtiqueta, JProgressBar unaBarraProgreso, registro_masivo rm) {
    etiqueta = unaEtiqueta;
    progreso = unaBarraProgreso;
    this.rm = rm;
}

/**
 * Tarea que tarda mucho y se ejecutara en un hilo separado.
 */
@Override
protected Double doInBackground() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("doInBackground() esta en el hilo "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    this.rm.lista_estudiantes_carrera(new conexion_base_de_datos().getConexion(),"TSU EN TURISMO");
    int conteo=0;
    int filas=0;

    progreso.setMaximum(rm.getEst_x_carrera().size());
    progreso.setStringPainted(true);


   for(int x=0; x<rm.getEst_x_carrera().size(); x++){ //recorriendo listado de estudiantes
       publish(x);
       System.out.println("_____________________________ESTUDIANTE N°: ("+x+")_________________________________");
       progreso.setString("CI: "+rm.getEst_x_carrera().get(x));

       rm.depurador_estudiantes_semestres(rm.getEst_x_carrera().get(x), "civil");//depurando estudiante por estudiante
        for(int i=0;i<rm.getCant_mat().size();i++){//recorriendo la cantidad de materia por semestre
            System.out.println("semestre "+(i+1)+" cantidad materias= "+rm.getCant_mat().get(i));
            conteo=conteo+rm.getCant_mat().get(i);//contando para sacar el total de materias que debe
        }//fin recorrido cantidad de materia por semestre
            conteo=0; //inicializando la variable para el conteo por cada estudiante de materias que en total debe


}//fin recorrido listado por estudiantes


    progreso.setMaximum(100);
    return  100.0;
}

/**
 * Tarea terminada, SwingWorker llama a este metodo en el hilo de despacho
 * de eventos. Aqui actualizamos la etiqueta para que ponga "Hecho".
 */
@Override
protected void done() {
    System.out.println("done() esta en el hilo "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    etiqueta.setText("hecho");
}

/**
 * SwingWorker llama a este metodo en el hilo de despacho de eventos cuando
 * llamamos a publish() y le pasa los mismos parametros que nosotros
 * pongamos en publish().<br>
 * En este ejemplo, nosotros pasamos el valor de la barra de progreso.
 */
@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
    System.out.println("process() esta en el hilo "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    progreso.setValue(chunks.get(0));
}







public static void main(String args[]){

 // La ventana principal, con una etiqueta que pondrá "Hecho" cuando
    // termine el SwingWorker.
    JFrame ventanaPrincipal = new JFrame();
    JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel("Sin hacer");
    ventanaPrincipal.getContentPane().add(etiqueta);
    ventanaPrincipal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventanaPrincipal.pack();
    ventanaPrincipal.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventanaPrincipal.setVisible(true);

    // Una ventana con la barra de progreso
    JProgressBar barraProgreso = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    JDialog dialogoProgreso = new JDialog(ventanaPrincipal, "progreso");
    dialogoProgreso.getContentPane().add(barraProgreso);
    dialogoProgreso.pack();
    dialogoProgreso.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    registro_masivo rm = new registro_masivo();


    // Hacemos visible la barra de progreso y lanzamos
    // el SwingWorker.
    dialogoProgreso.setVisible(true);
    barra_progreso worker = new barra_progreso(etiqueta, barraProgreso,rm);
    worker.execute();
    try {
        // Mostramos el resultado y ocultamos la barra de progreso.
        // Esta llamada se queda bloqueada hasta que termine
        // el SwingWorker. Debemos ocultar la barra de progreso
        // inmediatamente después.
        System.out.println("El resultado es " + worker.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(barra_progreso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(barra_progreso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto, la barra de progreso solo aparece mientras el metodo no haya terminado su ejecucion.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BackgroundWorkerDemo extends Application {

    Button taskButton;
    BorderPane mainPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        taskButton = new Button("Long Running Task");
        taskButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Running task");
                runTask();
            }
        });

        mainPane = new BorderPane();
        mainPane.setTop(taskButton);
        mainPane.setPrefSize(100,50);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void runTask() {

        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
        mainPane.setBottom(progress);

        Task<Void> longTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                //Invoke method that execute long duration tasks 
                longDurationMethod();
                return null;
            }
        };

        //When long task ends
        longTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                //Remove progress bar from main pane
                mainPane.getChildren().remove(progress);
            }
        });

        progress.progressProperty().bind(longTask.progressProperty());
        new Thread(longTask).start();

    }

    //Method that execute a long duration task
    public String longDurationMethod() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @JeanOV, bienvenido a [es.so]! ¡Gracias por tu aporte! En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? Quizás algunos comentarios en la líneas importantes ayudaría bastante, mostrando dónde iría el código del autor y cómo aumenta el porcentaje de la barra. En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?